# What is the difference between "to meet you" and "to meeting you"?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Why the below one is correct?

> I look forward **to meeting** you.

And why this one is wrong?

> I look forward **to meet** you.

I generally do these mistakes in letter writing.

Comment: It's similar to "look over at someone"; you "look forward to something". That's why you need a gerund, i.e. the *-ing* form, not an infinitive (basic form of the verb).

Comment: See also: [look forward to meet you, or to meeting you?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/28856/3281)

Comment: You say "I'm happy to meet you", you would never say "I look forward to meet you."

Comment: @Catija For the same reason you'd say "I look forward to the movie" but not "I'm happy to the movie" :-)

Comment: See also: [To + verb + '-ing' usage question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56296/to-verb-ing-usage-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the string `look forward to` is ***generally*** followed by 'verb-ing'.

> I look forward to meeting you 
>  I look forward to reading this book 
>  I look forward to making your acquaintance 
>  I look forward to speaking with him.

Check out the examples on [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/). **Most of them** follow this format. This is because in such structure, 'to' serves as a preposition and *not* the infinitive marker [Thanks Snailboat].

This is how it is -I just learned it that way! :)

Comment: Right, because this *to* is the preposition, not the infinitive marker.  *Look forward to* can also be followed by a regular noun phrase; search COCA for *looking forward to the* for some examples.

Comment: Hey, nice seeing you after long time @snailboat tip included! :)