# How to distinguish a preposition and an infinitive marker?

Tags: prepositions, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

My question hails from [this answer.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56296/to-verb-ing-usage-question)

Let's take one of the examples mentioned there.

> Seven steps ***to reaching*** your goals

Non-native speakers like me can identify **if the sentence** is already written. Say the one I just quoted. I see that 'to' is followed by 'verb-ing' **and therefore**, it's a preposition and not an infinitive marker.

**But**, I'm pretty sure that if I were to write this sentence, I'd have gone for...

> Seven steps ***to reach*** your goals

Now, the question is, how to identify whether we use 'to' as an infinite marker OR a preposition? I repeat, I'm asking about writing on my own, and **not** something that is already written.

---

The [similar question has been asked previously](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23999/when-to-use-gerund-or-infinitive) and the answer says that 'there's no such rule'. But then, Damkerng has come up with a very useful comment. I'm looking forward to having such kind of answer to this. If there's **no one rule**, at least something that helps us decide it?

Comment: By the way, *seven steps to reach(ing) your goals* isn't a sentence.  It's a noun phrase.

Comment: This is related to my comment [in another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55910/what-is-the-difference-between-the-two-phrases-to-meet-you-and-meeting-you#comment105669_55910). To keep things short, it's "to something" vs. "to do something". *I'd like to visit New York* ~ "I'd like to do something"; *Scientists are closer to being able to ..]* ~ "Scientists are closer to something"; *Seven steps to reaching your goals* ~ "Seven steps to something". IMHO, meaning always comes first in writing, and we should keep our thoughts clear. Clear thoughts, clear choices.

Comment: this is useful @DamkerngT. as always, sir! :)

Comment: Actually you want to know how to choose between gerund and infinitive, right?

Comment: @LucianSava bang on! welcome back! :)